# FragmentPagerAdapter doesn't start position from 0 after call notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a simple FragmentPagerAdapter class

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        PagerAdapter fragment;
                fragment = new PagerAdapter(data.get(position));

        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position >= pageCount || position < 0)
            return null;
        return "Profile " + position;
    }

}
```

that PagerAdapter is a simple class that extends from Fragment.
and then I set an instance of SectionsPagerAdapter to my ViewPager.

problem is here:

at first I have one page on view pager( data size is 1), when I get more data , I call SectionsPagerAdapter instance notifyDataSetChanged, but in getItem(int position) method instead of position start form 0, it start from 1 !!!

what should I do? I wanna re creat my view pager after I get more data
Thanks in advance

Comment: set adapter again instead of notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: You need to set the adapter to reset the position, notifyDataSetChanged is used to notify the adapter there is a data change so its rebind the data only.

Comment: another thing you can use   viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

Comment: @NiranjPatel pervious adapter?or new instance ? Thank u:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to set the adapter again to reset the position, notifyDataSetChanged is used to notify the adapter there is a data change so its rebind the data only.

Or You can use this code to move the view pager which position you want

`viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);`

Comment: I must call viewPager.setCurrentItem(0) after notifyDataSetChanged() or before it?
and another question is, i must get another instance of adapter and set it again to view pager, or can set again pervious one?

Comment: You can use both it's up to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` will only Notify any registered observers that the data set has changed regardless of touching viewPager positions.

> There are two different classes of data change events, item changes
>   and structural changes. Item changes are when a single item has its
>   data updated but no positional changes have occurred. Structural
>   changes are when items are inserted, removed or moved within the data
>   set.

You have to set viewPager's position to start page(position 0) manually *after notifyDataSetChanged()*.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Comment: accept Nithinlal because was first answer, Thank u anyway :)